# Why is this MySQL query incredibly slow and not using the right index?

Tags: mysql, database, performance, query-performance

This takes about 100 seconds to execute:

```
SELECT part.*
FROM   (((((((`part` 
              LEFT JOIN `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_x_part` 
                     ON `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_x_part`.`part_id` = 
                      `part`.`id`) 
             LEFT JOIN `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2` 
                    ON 
`engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_x_part`.`engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_id` 
= `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `engine_x_category_1` 
       ON `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2`.`engine_x_category_1_id` = 
          `engine_x_category_1`.`id`) 
 LEFT JOIN `engine` 
        ON `engine_x_category_1`.`engine_id` = `engine`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `model` 
       ON `engine`.`model_id` = `model`.`id`) 
 LEFT JOIN `year` 
        ON `model`.`year_id` = `year`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `make` 
       ON `year`.`make_id` = `make`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `category_1` 
      ON `engine_x_category_1`.`category_1_id` = `category_1`.`id` 
WHERE  1 > 0 
       AND `category_1`.`id` > 0 
GROUP  BY `part`.`id` 
ORDER  BY `part`.`id` ASC 
LIMIT  0, 20
```

However once we get rid of `AND category_1.id > 0`, it only takes 0.003 second.

This is really weird because `category_1.id` is the PRIMARY KEY column and table `category_1` has only **26** rows.

## Structure and keys of `category_1`

[image]

## Query EXPLAIN:

[image: MySQL EXPLAIN of this query]

What could be wrong here? Why isn't MySQL using the PRIMARY index for `category_1.id` but instead used index `ts` which is for a timestamp column?

P.S. MySQL version: 5.6.33

## UPDATE 1

As O. Jones pointed out, I tried `FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY)` with table `category_1` and EXPLAIN showed the query is correctly using PRIMARY instead of ts as the index for `category_1.id` but the query still took nearly 100 seconds to execute.

Seems `category_1.id` is NOT the culprit here.

## UPDATE 2

After the suggestion of @O.Jones, I got rid of the irrelevant JOINs on `make`, `year`, `model`, and `engine`:

```
SELECT part.*
FROM   (((`part` 
              LEFT JOIN `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_x_part` 
                     ON `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_x_part`.`part_id` = 
                      `part`.`id`) 
             LEFT JOIN `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2` 
                    ON 
`engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_x_part`.`engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_id` 
= `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `engine_x_category_1` 
       ON `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2`.`engine_x_category_1_id` = 
          `engine_x_category_1`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `category_1` 
      ON `engine_x_category_1`.`category_1_id` = `category_1`.`id` 
WHERE  1 > 0 
       AND `category_1`.`id` > 0 
GROUP  BY `part`.`id` 
ORDER  BY `part`.`id` ASC 
LIMIT  0, 20
```

[image: EXPLAIN]

Now the query is only taking about **0.003** second.

While this answers the question for this particular query, it is apparently **NOT** the ultimate solution, because one may as well need to search for auto parts by **both** the `category_1` and the `make`, thus unable to remove any JOINs in the query:

```
SELECT part.*
FROM   (((((((`part` 
              LEFT JOIN `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_x_part` 
                     ON `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_x_part`.`part_id` = 
                      `part`.`id`) 
             LEFT JOIN `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2` 
                    ON 
`engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_x_part`.`engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_id` 
= `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `engine_x_category_1` 
       ON `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2`.`engine_x_category_1_id` = 
          `engine_x_category_1`.`id`) 
 LEFT JOIN `engine` 
        ON `engine_x_category_1`.`engine_id` = `engine`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `model` 
       ON `engine`.`model_id` = `model`.`id`) 
 LEFT JOIN `year` 
        ON `model`.`year_id` = `year`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `make` 
       ON `year`.`make_id` = `make`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `category_1` 
      ON `engine_x_category_1`.`category_1_id` = `category_1`.`id` 
WHERE  1 > 0 
       AND `category_1`.`id` > 0
       AND `make`.`id` > 0
GROUP  BY `part`.`id` 
ORDER  BY `part`.`id` ASC 
LIMIT  0, 20
```

[image: EXPLAIN]

Which, after several tests, still run for about **80 - 100** seconds.

What should we do now?

## UPDATE 3

Following the suggestion of @LuisMuñoz, I moved the conditions from WHERE to the corresponding JOIN ON clauses:

```
SELECT part.*
FROM   (((((((`part` 
              LEFT JOIN `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_x_part` 
                     ON `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_x_part`.`part_id` = 
                      `part`.`id`) 
             LEFT JOIN `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2` 
                    ON 
`engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_x_part`.`engine_x_category_1_x_category_2_id` 
= `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `engine_x_category_1` 
       ON `engine_x_category_1_x_category_2`.`engine_x_category_1_id` = 
          `engine_x_category_1`.`id`) 
 LEFT JOIN `engine` 
        ON `engine_x_category_1`.`engine_id` = `engine`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `model` 
       ON `engine`.`model_id` = `model`.`id`) 
 LEFT JOIN `year` 
        ON `model`.`year_id` = `year`.`id`) 
JOIN `make` 
  ON `year`.`make_id` = `make`.`id` 
     AND `make`.`id` > 0) 
JOIN `category_1` 
 ON `engine_x_category_1`.`category_1_id` = `category_1`.`id` 
    AND `category_1`.`id` > 0 
WHERE  1 > 0 
GROUP  BY `part`.`id` 
LIMIT  0, 10
```

[image: EXPLAIN]

Had to use JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN or the conditions won't take effect.

However it's still as SLOW as when the conditions are in WHERE clause.

Comment: Please, format the query. It is unreadable.

Comment: Is there an index on `engine_x_category_1.category_1_id`, the query is scanning the full category_1 table like 4319/26 times.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Yes, `engine_x_category_1.category_1_id` is indexed as non-unique index.

Comment: `SELECT part.id AS part.id, .... part.category_2 AS part.category_2 .... GROUP BY part.id` is a invalid SQL query and cause invalid results. read ( https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/ )

Comment: @RaymondNijland GROUP BY here we use is for removing any duplicate part rows. Does this have anything to do with the performance issue here?

Comment: Use DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY when you are removing duplicates

Comment: @slaakso Thank you I will. But for now, I tried removing GROUP BY but still the query takes over 100 seconds. Any idea?

Comment: The indexes on your `category_1` table just don't matter. It has so few rows that indexed access is irrelevant. It's the indexes on your `parts` table that probably make a difference, and maybe on those `_category_` tables with long names. Notice that your `LEFT JOIN` to `category_1` is converted to an ordinary inner `JOIN` by the reference to a column in your `WHERE` clause.  Your query `SELECT`s no columns from some of the tables mentioned in your `LEFT JOIN` operations, so you could simplify your query at least for performance troubleshooting.

Comment: Also, please read this. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Please pay special attention to the section on query performance. Please [edit] your question to provide more details. And, avoid using images to show stuff like `EXPLAIN` output.  Instead paste the text and indent it four spaces.

Comment: @O.Jones You are right, I just tested the query with FORCE INDEX (PRIMARY) for table category_1 and it still took 100 seconds.

Comment: Try removing the outer JOIN on `category_1` and moving the condition to `LEFT JOIN engine_x_category_1` as `AND engine_x_category_1.category_1_id = category_1.id`

Comment: @LuisMuñoz That simply gives this error: Unknown column 'category_1.id' in 'where clause'

Comment: How about this and removing category_1 from WHERE: `LEFT JOIN engine_x_category_1 
       ON engine_x_category_1_x_category_2.engine_x_category_1_id = 
          engine_x_category_1.id
LEFT JOIN category_1 
      ON engine_x_category_1.category_1_id = category_1.id AND category_1.id > 0` . I would try also moving `make.id > 0` to the the `make`join.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Had to use JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN with the extra conditions for ON clause, and it's still SLOW as when they are in WHERE.

Comment: Start by removing all the unnecessary brackets

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks and just removed all 7 parenthesis from the query and tested again but it's still as slow as about 80 seconds.

Comment: Try comparing the EXPLAIN between versions of your query. I'm still worried by the fact that the number of rows read on engine_x_category_1 is high compared to the other tables. Perhaps is time to reformulate the questions you expect the query to answer. May be the time is correct given the data structure. How many rows is expected the query to return?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz The query is expected to return 1.8 million rows (without LIMIT). I changed `make.id > 0 AND category_1.id > 0` to `make.id = 2 AND category_1.id = 1` and it only took 0.002 second returning 59 rows. What does this mean?

Comment: What are the semantics of "`category_1`.`id` > 0"?  Are you using negative numbers for something?  Get rid of the `LEFTs`, they seem to be useless.  Get rid of the extra parens.  Why have `GROUP BY` if the `JOINs` are only for "normalization" (many:1)?

Answer (score 0):

Few recommendations to try to speed up the query (I looked at the last update, #3):

- Make sure the query doesn't return too many rows (no user needs to see more than X rows, when X is a reasonable number you define). It's best to filter rows by adding filtering conditions (which are indexed), but you can also add a LIMIT clause.
- Add indexes to speed up the search (the recommended indexes for this query are below).
- You are using LEFT to join to category_1, but you are filtering on the id of that table (`category_1.id > 0`). Therefore, you can remove the word LEFT to INNER JOIN to that table instead, which may speed up the query.

Add the following indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `category_1` ADD INDEX `category_1_idx_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `engine_x_category_1` ADD INDEX `engine_x_category_1_idx_id` (`category_1_id`);
ALTER TABLE `make` ADD INDEX `make_idx_id` (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `part` ADD INDEX `part_idx_id` (`id`);
```